# iOS or android development, how to expire an application after a certain time

Tags: android, ios

I have a client that wants to build in a timed expiration after the date of installation.

Whether this is a good idea or not, aside, I know I can render the application basically useless by disabling functionality after a certain time after installation.

My question is, will such an idea be ok to the apple store reviewers and android reviewers?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, since you are asking for opinions on how people might react.

Comment: The iOS AppStore guidelines are pretty clear on that one: Don't do it, or you will be rejected.

Comment: @Sam True, it wasn't really a programming question.  I was asking the software dev community for a dev related issue.

Comment: @JustSid Where in the guidelines does it say that?  I was reading them and couldn't find it....

Answer (score 0):

There are no Android reviewers. If the app compiles, you can publish it to Google Play. As far as disabling, you can simply create some sort of Date object on the first launch of the app and then save the long that represents that Date to SharedPreferences. Then when the length of time has elapsed that you'd like to disable the app, just have the app show a dialog that says its disabled and basically cut off all functionality that way. In other words, make the entire app's functionality at that point just be displaying that the app has been disabled...just cutting off access to whatever other functionality. Or just direct the app to an Acitivity that displays this info instead of the actual usable app.

Quick mockup:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        long time = sharedPreferences.getLong("install_date", 0);
        if(time!=0) {
            Date installDate = new Date(time);
            Date now = new Date();
            int secondsBetween = (int) (installDate.getTime() - now.getTime()); //gives you seconds between
            if(secondsBetween==???) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, AppDisabled.class));
            }

        }
```